# Adding delay between separately started animations

Tags: jquery, animation, delay

I have an array with image URLs I add to a page as `img` tags. I add them hidden and fade them in when they are loaded. This works, but I'd like to add a bit of delay between each of them so it's not so much fading in at the same time.

```
function ajaxCallback(data)
{
    if(data && data.images)
        for(var n in data.images)
        {
            var image = $('<img>')
                .prop(data.images[n])
                .css({opacity: 0})
                .appendTo('#output')
                .load(imageLoaded);
        }
}

function imageLoaded()
{
    $(this)
        .animate({opacity: 1});
}
```

At the moment, if they load quick enough, they will all basically fade in at once. I'd like a bit of delay between each. Tried adding a call to `delay`, but that didn't seem to do much. Thinking I might have to do something with a queue or something, but can't quite get how to do this.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Please don't write tags in titles.

Answer (score 1):

In a similar case (not related to images), I use a recursive function that extracts the first element of the array, does its work, and calls itself when it finish. In your case, you should call the function again in the callback of `animate()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `setTimeout` in the `imageLoaded()` method and give a random value (within some bounds) for the timer.

```
function imageLoaded()
{
   var self = $(this);
   setTimeout(function(){
                            self.animate({opacity: 1});
                        }, 
              Math.random()*2000 //will fire sometime between 0 to 2000 milliseconds
             ); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
for (var n in data.images) {
    $('<img>').prop('src', data.images[n]).css({ // don't forget "src"
        opacity: 0
    })
      .appendTo('#output')
      .bind('reveal', imageLoaded); // bind a custom event
}

function imageLoaded() {
    $(this).animate({
        opacity: 1
    }, function(){ // wait until animation is done via callback
        $(this).next().trigger('reveal'); // then trigger the next reveal
    });
}

$('#output').find('img:first').load(function() { // when first image is loaded
    $(this).trigger('reveal'); // trigger its event to start the cascade
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/redler/mBfpG/

Comment: What happens if it takes too long between two images loads?

Comment: Well, you said you'd like a delay between loads. As this is written, it's just a callback when each animation is complete. If one particular load is taking too long, it would of course delay the rest of the chain. If you don't want this dependency and you have some idea of what "too long" is, then you probably want a deterministic triggering mechanism based on `setTimeout`.

Comment: What I meant was, what if the next one takes too long, so that when one finishes and trigger reveal, the next isn't done loading yet.

Comment: @Svish, I see what you're asking. What you can do is wrap the "animate the next reveal" logic with `.load( fn )`. The `fn` function will only fire after the selected element's load is completed. You can do this where you trigger the `reveal` -- something like `$(this).next().load( function(){ $(this).trigger('reveal'); } );`